# MAC address can be used to generate an IPv6 link local address

Tags: ipv6, mac-address

MAC address can be used to generate an IPv6 link local address.
What is the process of using MAC address to derive an IPv6 address ?

What are the problems that can be caused due to process of using MAC address to derive an IPv6 address  and how
are they overcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#appendix-A) has the full explanation.

Basically, you split the 48-bit MAC address down the middle, insert `FFFE` to extend it to 64 bits, and flip the U/L bit. This creates the 64-bit Interface ID which you append to the end of the 64 bits of the Global Routing Prefix and Subnet ID combination. For Link-local addresses, the created Interface ID is appended to the Link-local prefix (`FE80:0:0:0::`).

Some people are concerned that you can use a unique number, like a MAC address, to track a particular host. To correct this, [RFC 4941, Privacy Extensions for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941) was created. Windows and many Linux variants use random addressing by default, but this may be disabled.

Comment: god explanation https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736439(v=ws.10).aspx